# Can't create new project in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, report

We're switching over to Team Foundation for our version control, and I have to learn it and set it up.  Our IT guy did the installation of the both the data tier and the app tier, and he is of course convinced that it's right.  However when i log in as tfssetup and try to create a new project, i get the error:

```
Error 
Insufficient permissions to create a new SQL Server Reporting Services at tsttfsapp1.  

Explanation 
The permissions granted your user name and ID on the SQL Server Reporting Services at     tsttfsapp1 do not allow you create a new project. You must be granted specific permission by the server administrator.  

User Action 
Contact the Administrator for the SQL Server Reporting Services at tsttfsapp1 and ask that the permission "Content Manager" be added to your user account
```

So i tried to log in to http://servername/Reports_TFS it asks for the credentials but doesn't accept them.  Even stranger when i try to access it from a computer and user that aren't on the same domain as the app tier server, it doesn't ask for credentials and lets me right in.  As far as i know the default name of the site should be Reports, not Reports_TFS is it possible that his renaming of that could be causing the problem?

tfssetup is definitely a "Content Manager" as far as i can tell, so i don't understand why we are getting this problem.  Also any recommendation for good websites or books that can take a complete beginner and help me become an expert in 3 weeks (what's left of the 6 week time frame allowed for me to learn) would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out it was only a problem because I was using a 2005 client with a 2008 server.  A 2008 client has no problem creating a project on the 2008 server, but the 2005 client is not able to create a project on a 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but we had this error at my place of work on our 2005 TFS server. We opened a ticket with Microsoft and sent them our TFS database. They were able to replicate the issue with the copy of the database. Somehow the TFS database had gotten into an invalid state, but they weren't able to determine how this happened or how to fix it. Unfortunately, this error kept us from being able to upgrade the server to TFS 2008 too. We ended up getting latest of all the code and adding it to source control on a new install of TFS. What a pain.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, unfortunately we don't have a database yet, this is during our initial setup, trying to create the first project.  However your story gives me concerns about switching to TFS if it has weird issues like that.